# How to convert separate linked faces to individual meshes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, three.js

I managed to fill the volume of a mesh with many cubes via Geometry Nodes. And I even managed to render the result as a mesh (using the "Realize mesh" node and "Object => convert => mesh). Now I have one mesh with lots of individual cubes, which all belong to the same mesh. I hope the screenshot helps depicturing the situation.

Is there a function in Blender that allows me to convert ALL individually linked faces into separate meshes AT ONCE? Or do I have to do that manually?

(And eventually keep them together in a group? - The idea is to export the all those meshes to three.js and collect them into an array in order to do some animation stuff on them...)

I use Blender 3.6.2 on a MacBook Pro.

[image: One mesh with many indivudally linked faces]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the object consisting of the multiple cubes and <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*.
2. Press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate* and choose *By Loose Parts*.

   [image: separate]
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode* and all new objects should still be selected. Press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Move to Collection*, choose *New Collection*, enter a name for it and hit *OK*. But you could have also moved the original object to a new collection before separating.

   [image: new collection]
4. Now the objects should still be selected (or you can select them by right-clicking the new collection in the *Outliner* and choose *Select Objects*), right-click in the *3D Viewport* and choose *Set Origin* > *Origin to Geometry*.

   [image: set origin]

Comment: Gordon Brinkman: This is absolutely fantastic! Thank you so very much! :-)

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there a way to order the cube in a particular way? Right now the cubes are created rather arbitrary (which I only found out when exporting to Three).

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon Brinkmann ! – I appreciate your comment on the "new question" idea, but I consider this topic as very much related to the initial question. Would I post a new question, I would have to explain the previous steps all along again. – Anyway, meanwhile I will try to solve the problem in Three. – Thank you very much again! :-)

Comment: As I mentioned, I appreciate your suggestion and I will post the problem as a new question, if it remains one. In this case I have a different point of view than you have (even though you yourself write "it is PREFERRED to"), and it is as much viable as your point of view. So let's please not get lost in such a time wasting discussion. It is not my first "visit" on stackoverflow/stackexchange, it is not the first problem I post, it is not the first comment I give, it is not the first time I have to join such a discussion. I am familiar with the rules. Let's get back to work.

Comment: Just found this tutorial about sorting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poz9i4DCISo&list=PLV0Zsi5ZYUauI-Nh-G7InL5Jd-F6uvWvO&index=5

Comment: I really do not understand why you keep hitting on me. It is MY question, and also I can add solutions to it, which is, what I do, so I can find all the answer(s) should I look for them in the future. It is helpful for me, and, since it collects answers, it will be helpful for others, too (not everybody, obviously – you being one example for the exception –, but there are people out there, who I know think the same way I do.) – If this is really such a problem for you, feel free to downvote or delete or whatever. But to be not so friendly: It is getting ridiculous.

Comment: @RobertWildling Yes, it will be helpful for others, but: people searching to sort objects will not get the tutorial link by searching this forum for "sorting", because question and answer are about "separating". The search function only gives results on keywords in questions and answers, not comments. That was the reason why I thought it would be more helpful to others' issues if you would have put a new question for it. Or at least another answer here which can be found when searching for it... That's all I asked for in the beginning, but for some reason you took this as a personal offense.

Comment: ...you could even edit your question to include asking how to sort the objects and others can find it then. This will make my answer incomplete, but you are free to take back the acception.

Comment: Gordon – you will have to deal with it that I just might add more answers to this topic, even if you do not agree with my approach of handling this. As I said: feel free to downvote, delete, tell the moderators, whatever... I need infos in one place, and this is how I will also handle this topic. Also, if you take the time and use the search (which you quite obviously didn't) you'll find enough answers on "How to I find the index of...". A new question on that topic will most likely be downvoted. I have a feeling this is not over...